# using contour() in R to make shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile

How to use the output from `contour()`, which is just x, y and z data, to make a shapefile of the contour lines for output into ArcMap?

Comment: You can't use the output from `contour()` because it does not return anything, but the return from `contourLines()` is usable as explained below.

Answer (score 6):

As a matter of fact there is a function for that in package `maptools`: `ContourLines2SLDF` converts the output of `contourLines` into a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` object.

```
cl <- contourLines(volcano)
shp <- ContourLines2SLDF(cl)
```

You can then save it to a file using `maptools`'s `writeSpatialShape` or `rgdal`'s `writeOGR`.